# Integration of a symmetric function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

I have a bit of confusion about the following situation. Let's assume that we have a symmetric function $f(x,y)$ where it has the property $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ for all $x$ and $y$. $x$ and $y$ have the same domain as result. We have $p_y(y) = \int f(x,y)dx$ and $p_x(x)=\int f(x,y)dy$. I want to show that $p_y(.) = p_x(.)$.

This is nearly a trivial problem actually, but I am uneasy with some notational issues. Let's fix $y=a$. When we have $p_y(a) = \int f(x,a)dx$ , I replace the integrand as $p_y(a)=\int f(x,a)dx = \int f(a,x)dx = p_x(a)$. In the last step I integrate over $x$, but this second variable actually corresponds to $y$ actually in the original function $f(x,y)$. In order to justify that, I think of two reasons

1. Since the variable of integration $dx$ is a bound variable in $\int f(a,x) dx$, it doesn't matter which variable we are using inside the integral, so $$\int f(a,x)dx = \int f(a,y)dy = p_x(a)$$
2. To make it look more rigorous, I think of a identity variable transformation $y(x)=x$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1$ and

$$p_y(a) = \int f(x,a)dx =  \int f(a,y(x))dx = \int f(a,y)dy = p_x(a)$$

Which is the correct approach? How should I handle such situations in similar problems, when there are switch of variables like that?

Comment: The first approach is perfectly fine.